# Thinking-spinx breaks belongs_to built-in validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, thinking-sphinx

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Rails 5.0.0
- ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
- gem 'mysql2',          '~> 0.3.18', :platform => :ruby
- gem 'thinking-sphinx', '~> 3.2.0'
- PostgreSQL 9.5.3

I set up the Sphinx search engine in my Rails 5 project and it broke the Rails `belongs_to` built-in validation. Example:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user 
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :articles
end
```

Earlier when I created a new `Post` and did not set the `User` (as the parent) in the `Post`'s `new` form, Rails fired the validation error:

```
1 error prohibited this post from being saved:
User must exist
```

Now after adding Shpinx this validation does not happen anymore (at the `Post` creation). A new `Post` is silently created with an empty `user_id` field.

Same problem happens now to the `Article` model too - it happens with whatever models which have the `belongs_to` association.

How to fix this problem? Of course, I could simply add `validates :user, presence: true` to both Post and Article models - but I don't like such clumsy solutions.

NOTE: If I comment out the `gem 'thinking-sphinx', '~> 3.2.0'` line in my `Gemfile` - the described problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a Thinking Sphinx bug, which I've [just fixed](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/commit/3138fea725e009b91c1275481b02c5cab7d023b5).

You can use the latest by having this code in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '~> 3.2.0',
  :git    => 'git://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx.git',
  :branch => 'develop',
  :ref    => '3138fea725'
```