# accepts_nested_attributes_for depends on Thinking Sphinx (bug?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Rails 5.0.0
- ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
- gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18', :platform => :ruby
- gem 'thinking-sphinx', '~> 3.2.0'
- PostgreSQL 9.5.3

I set up the Sphinx search engine in my Rails 5 project and it (probably) broke the Rails **accepts_nested_attributes_for** method. At least **accepts_nested_attributes_for** method works only if I set these lines in **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'mysql2',          '~> 0.3.18', :platform => :ruby
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '~> 3.2.0'
```

Without these lines **accepts_nested_attributes_for** doesn't work! "doesn't work" means that the nested model is not created through the parent creation form (I get the error:

> 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: Articles user must
>   exist

)

I uploaded my project to Heroku and problem **happened there too** - exactly the same way (even despite Heroku does not support Sphinx for free).

Here is my test project on GitHub: https://github.com/dorelly2/test-project . This is merely a scaffold-generated test project.

I made 2 Heroku apps which demonstrate the different behavior dependent on whether the 2 lines (mentioned above) are commented out or not in Gemfile. You can play with them and see. Try to create a user with `Name` and `Article title` in both apps and you'll see the difference:

https://test-project-ts.herokuapp.com/

https://test-project-ts-bad.herokuapp.com/

Here are the code samples:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
...

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :articles, Article.new do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label "Article title" %>
      <%= ff.text_field :title %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
...
```

Controllers are scaffold-generated - no point to show them here.

What's going on? Can somebody clearify? Does **accepts_nested_attributes_for** generally work without Thinking Sphinx?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a change in behaviour in Rails/ActiveRecord 5.0, and a bug in Thinking Sphinx stopped it from working: `belongs_to` associations default to having a validation in place.

The bug in TS is fixed, though a new version isn't released yet with that fix. Detailed here: [Thinking-spinx breaks belongs_to built-in validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890554/thinking-spinx-breaks-belongs-to-built-in-validation)

Comment: No, it didn't help. I installed your fixed TS and **accepts_nested_attributes_for** even stopped to work with it. Could you please download my sourcecodes (from Git) and ckeck them on your computer?

Comment: I wonder where the bug is actually located - inside accepts_nested_attributes_for or inside TS? Does accepts_nested_attributes_for generally work itself - I mean on a computer where TS was never installed?

Comment: Just to be clear: the belongs_to association now adds a validation by default, and this is what the error is related to. You can disable this behaviour if you'd like: `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false`

Comment: I got it. I tried to set `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_b‌​y_default = false` and it worked. Thank you for your help! Now I understand what's going on: The bug in TS is equivalent to `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_b‌​y_default = false` - so uncommenting the buggy TS in Gemfile allows **accepts_nested_attributes_for** to work - the same way as `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_b‌​y_default = false` allows **accepts_nested_attributes_for** to work.

Comment: But another question arises: it looks like in Rails 5 **accepts_nested_attributes_for** now requires `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_b‌​‌​y_default = false` to be set so **accepts_nested_attributes_for** could work? Can this be called a bug inside **accepts_nested_attributes_for**? How do you think? Perhaps it is necessary to post this bug to some bugtracker?

Comment: I'm not sure if it classifies as a _bug_ - you're trying to create articles without specifying the user for these articles. If you're happy to have articles without users, then you can either disable the functionality completely, or just for the association using the `:optional` option: `belongs_to :user, :optional => true`. But, if you want the user saved for each article, maybe add a hidden field in your form for `user_id`? Of course, that'll only work if the user is already persisted to the database.

Comment: Don't use ever use **accepts_nested_attributes_for**? 

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html : `Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent.`

**accepts_nested_attributes_for** creates a user and his dependent article _simultaneously_  - in a single (parent object's) form. I don't know how does **accepts_nested_attributes_for** internally work (but you can look at its sourcecodes at the very bottom of the page). So I'd say this is a bug.